# In rdlc split(winform) get last index value of array

Tags: asp.net, winforms

In `rdlc split(winform)` how to get last index value of an array. For example.

```
=Split(First(Fields!ID.Value),",")(2).
```

In this, How to take the value 2 as the last index value of the splitted array?

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution, Actually , ,my problem was to get 'ghj' from 'xxxxx F/O ghj'. i accomplished , it by first replacing 'F/O' with comma and then spliting based on comma

SPLIT(Replace(Fields!Name.Value,"F/O",","),",")(1)